# Installing PyTorch under conda fails with permissions error and Rolling back transaction

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, conda

I'd like to use PyTorch in a Python program. The instructions for installing it require conda. After installing Conda I ran:

```
>conda install -c pytorch pytorch (as instructed on the PyTorch [page][1])
```

It looked promising -- until the end.

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pytorch


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    icc_rt-2017.0.4            |       h97af966_0         8.0 MB
    vs2015_runtime-15.5.2      |                3         2.2 MB
    pytorch-0.4.0              |py36_cuda80_cudnn7he774522_1       529.2 MB      pytorch
    mkl-2018.0.3               |                1       178.1 MB
    numpy-1.14.5               |   py36h9fa60d3_4          35 KB
    intel-openmp-2018.0.3      |                0         1.7 MB
    numpy-base-1.14.5          |   py36h5c71026_4         3.8 MB
    vc-14.1                    |       h0510ff6_3           5 KB
    blas-1.0                   |              mkl           6 KB
    conda-4.5.8                |           py36_0         1.0 MB
    mkl_fft-1.0.2              |   py36hb217b18_0         113 KB
    mkl_random-1.0.1           |   py36h77b88f5_1         268 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       724.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:           1.0-mkl
    icc_rt:         2017.0.4-h97af966_0
    intel-openmp:   2018.0.3-0
    mkl:            2018.0.3-1
    mkl_fft:        1.0.2-py36hb217b18_0
    mkl_random:     1.0.1-py36h77b88f5_1
    numpy:          1.14.5-py36h9fa60d3_4
    numpy-base:     1.14.5-py36h5c71026_4
    pytorch:        0.4.0-py36_cuda80_cudnn7he774522_1 pytorch

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:          4.5.4-py36_0                               --> 4.5.8-py36_0
    vc:             14-h0510ff6_3                              --> 14.1-h0510ff6_3
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-3                               --> 15.5.2-3

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
icc_rt-2017.0.4      |  8.0 MB | ############################################################################## | 100%
vs2015_runtime-15.5. |  2.2 MB | ############################################################################## | 100%
pytorch-0.4.0        | 529.2 MB | ############################################################################# | 100%
mkl-2018.0.3         | 178.1 MB | ############################################################################# | 100%
numpy-1.14.5         |   35 KB | ############################################################################## | 100%
intel-openmp-2018.0. |  1.7 MB | ############################################################################## | 100%
numpy-base-1.14.5    |  3.8 MB | ############################################################################## | 100%
vc-14.1              |    5 KB | ############################################################################## | 100%
blas-1.0             |    6 KB | ############################################################################## | 100%
conda-4.5.8          |  1.0 MB | ############################################################################## | 100%
mkl_fft-1.0.2        |  113 KB | ############################################################################## | 100%
mkl_random-1.0.1     |  268 KB | ############################################################################## | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
```

But then this.

```
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Apparently it was at least partly installed because PyCharm was able to see it. But when I asked PyCharm to install it in an environment, I got this error.

```
RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.
```

It suggests an alternative way to install PyTorch.  So I tried that.

```
>conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torchvision

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

But when I do that and search for PyTorch, I eventually find myself back at the original instructions.

When I search for Torchvision, no Windows versions are listed.

Comment: Are you running the Windows cmd as administrator? If you are using Anaconda, right click on it and select Run as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following steps in Windows:

1. Create a virtual environment using the command :

   `conda create -n py_env python=3.5`
2. `source activate py_env`
3. `conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch`
4. `pip install torchvision`

Note: You can use any name instead of `py_env`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your platform?

For your first installation method, the error message says that you don't have the permission. I encountered that error before on a Linux system. The reason was that Anaconda was installed by another user. I configured the path to point python to that installation so that I could run python without installing my own copy of Anaconda. However, it didn't permit me installing new packages and I got the same error message.

Solution: I installed my own copy of Anaconda and everything worked.

Comment: could you please tell how to install the pytorch-cpu and torchvision-cpu without using conda. I have created a virtual environment, I want to install it there. (CPU machine, Ubuntu 16.04, NO CUDA support). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just run:

```
pip install torch torchvision
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to install PyTorch is the following steps:

1. `conda create -n pytorch_env python=3`
2. `source activate pytorch_env`
3. `conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision -c pytorch`
4. Go to python shell and import using the command

   `import torch`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal in administrative mode and if you are in linux try
sudo pip install  "your package name"