# Anoconda does not allow Torchvision to be installed

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

I tried the following commands 
conda create -n torch_env -c pytorch pytorch torchvision
conda install -c soumith/label/pytorch torchvision
conda install -c soumith torchvision

Provided by Anaconda but none of them works. Please help me I am stack !

Error message:
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- torchvision

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469194/installing-pytorch)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12210

Then I found that torchvision should be installed together with pytorch in anaconda.

```
conda install -c pytorch torchvision
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your anwser.

Comment: @YLR To explain this post, -c does not indicate that you are somehow installing pytorch with torchvision, -c indicates the --channel. Anyone can create channels for people to install programs from through conda and presumably the pytorch team has done the same or someone has on their behalf. It just means that through the default download options it is not available, but it is through the 'pytorch' custom channel.

Answer (score -1):

I just found the answer to my question.

torchvision is not available in Anaconda Cloud. Instead, I used this command and it worked fine:

```
pip install torchvision
```

Comment: I do not what you googled to get that script to install, but in the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) everything is fine!