# Django web Deployment Failed on azure

Tags: python, django, azure, pytorch, web-deployment

```
10:47:19 AM django-face-restore: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==TORCH_VERSION+cpu (from versions: 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0)
10:47:19 AM django-face-restore: ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==TORCH_VERSION+cpu
10:47:19 AM django-face-restore: WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
10:47:19 AM django-face-restore: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/8da12d59fc3e034/antenv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
10:47:19 AM django-face-restore: "2022-03-31 07:00:00"|ERROR|Failed pip installation with exit code: 1
10:47:21 AM django-face-restore: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -i /tmp/8da12d59fc3e034 --compress-destination-dir -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log 
10:47:21 AM django-face-restore: Deployment Failed
```

Comment: I think the problem occurred, when it try to install torch from the requirements.txt file

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this `ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==TORCH_VERSION+cpu` error:

You need to install the specific version of `torch`, try either of the following ways:

Add the following to your `requirements.txt` file:

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

torch==1.7.0+cpu
```

OR

```
python -m pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

OR

```
python3.8 -m pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio==0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

References: [Install PyTorch from requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60912744/install-pytorch-from-requirements-txt) , [ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cpu](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47354)
, and [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901682/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-3-1/58902298#58902298)