# I am not able to install pytorch in jupyter and Spyder?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch, spyder

I have tried installing pytorch on jupyter and spyder but it is not working. I have install it in conda env, from pytorch documentation tried everything.

1. [From pytorch documentation and it shows pytorch installed 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSsh1.png)
2. [In conda env. Installed for jupyter and spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys5kc.png)
3. [In conda list pytorch is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcIXe.png)
4. [I have tried to open from app after installing in conda env. But it is Not opening here in jupyter, a pop up window appears each time for 1-2 seconds then disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmpPc.png)

Is there any other way to install it ?? Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing PyTorch under conda fails with permissions error and Rolling back transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469194/installing-pytorch-under-conda-fails-with-permissions-error-and-rolling-back-tra)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the quality of your questions

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simply that conda fails to install pytorch; this can have multiple causes. Forget about spyder and jupyter, they're not the issue.

> *1. From pytorch documentation and it shows pytorch installed 100%*

No it doesn't. Look at the bottom line: `Rolling back transaction: ...working... done`. **conda did not successfully install the package.** You need to debug further why (permissions issue on directory? installing under userid? dependency conflict?) Follow my suggestions at bottom.

> *2. In conda env. Installed for jupyter and spyder*

No they don't! They only show that conda has (previously) installed the jupyter and spyder executables. Those don't tell you which conda packages are installed. That's what `conda list` does.

> *3. In conda list pytorch is not showing*

Correct. Because it never installed it in the first place, as per 1. above.

You must debug why step 1. fails. There are many possible causes and you haven't given enough debugging information that we can tell which.

Please post extra information on why it fails. Suggest you do the following:

- Try just `conda install pytorch -c pytorch` by itself, not all the other packages, they make constraint solving harder.
- Try verbose mode: `conda install -v pytorch -c pytorch`

  - verbose mode should show you why conda thinks it needs to roll back the transaction (e.g. conflicting dependencies for 2+ different packages)
- Check which user and permissions you're doing conda install under, are they the same as the Anaconda install? (often if you use the GUI installer under Windows/Linux/Mac, it assumes it can/should as admin or else user, without asking you).
- In rare cases, you might need to nuke your conda environment and create a new env. I'd do this if you can't debug it after say 48+ hours. If you install every package under 'base', in particular for R as well as Python, this is a known issue. Even if doesn't break things, using 'base' environment for too many things tends to slow down constraint solving to take many hours, or hang forever.
- Finally, after you do finally get the package installed, see if you need to set PYTHONPATH (either/both inside the Anaconda GUI package manager, and in the Unix shell .bashrc/Windows environment settings).
- See the anaconda doc and also SO and the many good third-party blogs out there.